# How to use binValue with LIKE %%

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MySql request (it work) :

```
SELECT `membre_pseudo` FROM `membres` WHERE lower(`membre_pseudo`) LIKE "louis%" ORDER BY `membre_pseudo`
```

But when I add variables in my php script like that it returns a blank page :

```
$query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT `:field` FROM `:table` WHERE lower(`:field`) LIKE ":search%" ORDER BY `:field`');
    $query->bindValue(':field',$field,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(':table',$table,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(':search',$search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        echo '<suggest>'.$row[$field].'</suggest>';
    }
    $query->closeCursor();
    echo '</suggests>';
```

Have you an idea ?

Louis

Comment: fyi: you cannot bind table/column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @u_mulder but I have to make tables and fields as variables. So I did this :

```
<?php
require_once(BASEPATH. 'config.php');
//Sécurité pour empêcher d'interroger la base librement : liste des table et des champs utilisables
$check = array(
    'membres' => array('membre_pseudo')
);

$table = (isset($_GET['table']) ? $_GET['table'] : '');
$field = (isset($_GET['field']) ? $_GET['field'] : '');
$search = (isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '');

if(isset($check[$table]) && in_array($field, $check[$table])){ //Vérification
    if($table && $field && $search){
        $search = strtolower(mysql_escape_string($search));

                echo '<suggests>';

                $query = $bdd->query('SELECT `'.$field.'` FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE lower(`'.$field.'`) LIKE "'.$search.'%" ORDER BY `'.$field.'`');
        while($row = $query->fetch()){
            echo '  <suggest>'.$row[$field].'</suggest>';
        }
        $query->closeCursor();

        echo '</suggests>';
    }
}
else{
    die('Requête interdite');
} 
?>
```

I've integrated a security check to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ghost mentioned you cannot bind table names and field names, so your query should be rewritten, for example:

```
$query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT `field_name` 
    FROM `table_name` 
    WHERE lower(`field_name`) 
    LIKE :search 
    ORDER BY `field_name`');
```

Note, that you don't need `"` around `:search` placeholder.

Also I don't understand why you bind `:search` as `PARAM_INT`, I think it should be string:

```
$query->bindValue(':search', $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR); // add % sign here
```

Also PDO has function to check if any errors occured during execution - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php Read and use it.

Comment: and the alternative would be to just whitelist table/column names

Comment: @u_mulder I've done a mistake it's actually not PARAM_INT but PARAM_STR. Topic edited